# Laravel - passing php variable to JS as array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, variables

Im trying to pass result from database to js variable as array:

```
        $test_min_max_list = TestsMinMax
        ::join('results', 'tests_min_max.id', '=', 'results.test_result_id')
        ->select('created_at','min','avg','max')
        ->where([
            ['results.user_id', '=', $user_id],
            ['results.test_id', '=', $request->get('test_id')],
        ])->get();
```

**Return view for variable:**

```
    return view('results', [
        'test_min_max_list' => $test_min_max_list
    ]);
```

**Result on page:**

```
{{$test_min_max_list}}
```

->

```
[{"created_at":"2018-01-13 22:47:17","min":0.29999999999999999,"avg":0.40000000000000002,"max":0.53000000000000003},{"created_at":"2018-01-13 22:48:58","min":0.29999999999999999,"avg":0.76300000000000001,"max":1.972},{"created_at":"2018-01-13 22:54:51","min":0.93899999999999995,"avg":2.0409999999999999,"max":3.3500000000000001},{"created_at":"2018-01-14 14:38:31","min":0.36699999999999999,"avg":0.39400000000000002,"max":0.42299999999999999},{"created_at":"2018-01-14 18:27:06","min":0.29699999999999999,"avg":0.44900000000000001,"max":0.90000000000000002},{"created_at":"2018-02-17 13:07:04","min":0.29499999999999998,"avg":0.30599999999999999,"max":0.34000000000000002},{"created_at":"2018-02-18 11:29:35","min":0.35999999999999999,"avg":0.38500000000000001,"max":0.40000000000000002}]
```

**Result in variable:**

```
var test = {!! json_encode($test_min_max_list->toArray()) !!};
```

->

```
Array [length: 0]
```

How can I fix that and get an working array?

Comment: Try converting the SQL result to JSON array in the controller and just spitting out a variable `{{ $text_min_max_list }}` in the view

Comment: @ezw, Tried that and get: `ErrorException: Call to a member function toArray() on string`

Comment: What is that after the `->` after `Result on page:`? Is that what that variable holds? Isn't that already in JSON? Why are you encoding a JSON array to JSON again?

Comment: Yes, its a result which is displayed on page when i put php variable just in HTML, but I need those data in js variable which i can use after to build a chart. If i just use `var test = {!! ($test_min_max_list) !!};` the test var is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $test_min_max_list = TestsMinMax
    ::join('results', 'tests_min_max.id', '=', 'results.test_result_id')
    ->select('created_at','min','avg','max')
    ->where([
        ['results.user_id', '=', $user_id],
        ['results.test_id', '=', $request->get('test_id')],
    ])->get()->toArray();
```

In JS script

```
var array = {{ json_encode($test_min_max_list) }};
```

Comment: Result: ErrorException: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: @ezw also same error. Mabey the problem is in returning variable to view?    `return view('results', [
            'test_min_max_list' => $test_min_max_list
        ]);`

Answer (score 0):

@ezw @It is all yours

I figured out what is the problem... I totally missed out that I'm passing:

```
['results.user_id', '=', $user_id],
['results.test_id', '=', $request->get('test_id')],
```

those data thru AJAX and I was running

```
var test = {!! json_encode($test_min_max_list->toArray()) !!};
```

this variable before that, thats why it was empty...
**Sorry for the confusion.**